# Changing package install order in Python

Tags: python, django, heroku, dependencies, pip

Does anyone know if package install order matters in Python? More specifically my pip `requirements.txt` for a Django website I am building was:

```
Django==1.4
MySQL-python==1.2.3
django-evolution==0.6.7
django-pagination==1.0.7
boto==2.5.2
numpy==1.6.2
requests==0.13.1
simplejson==2.5.2
gunicorn==0.14.6
```

When deploying to Heroku the application would crash with the following error:

```
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:20132 (4)
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2012-08-05T09:26:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:26:56 [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2012-08-05T09:26:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-08-05T09:26:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2012-08-05T09:27:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage: gunicorn [options]
2012-08-05T09:27:17+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: no such option: --workers
2012-08-05T09:27:17+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-05T09:27:17+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-05 09:27:17 [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
```

Where my `Procfile` is as follows:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn commerical_production.wsgi:application --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

The problem was fixed by simply changing the order of requirements to:

```
Django==1.4
gunicorn==0.14.6
MySQL-python==1.2.3
django-evolution==0.6.7
django-pagination==1.0.7
boto==2.5.2
numpy==1.6.2
requests==0.13.1
simplejson==2.5.2
```

(note that `gunicorn` is now moved to the top)

I found this out by luckily guessing to try and change the order of the imports but my question is has anyone else run into this problem or know why the order of the packages makes a difference when installed from the `requirements.txt`? Could this problem indicative of some larger dependency issue that is in my app?

Comment: This should usually not matter, since everything has to be installed before the application is allowed to run. Not sure if heroku is doing something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip is not very good at handling package dependencies as easy_install. We had the same problem in our project. Even though the order in req.txt was correct, we had dependency problems that is related to order.

My solution is to feed the req.txt to easy_install, but than you should be careful with the packages that is editable or those from github etc.

You may want to check below links:

http://metak4ml.blogspot.com/2009/08/easyinstall-read-pip-requirementstxt.html
http://community.webfaction.com/questions/1220/using-easy_install-to-get-all-dependencies-listed-in-requirementstxt (while read line answer is close to what we do)

Answer (score 0):

Pyton setup install scripts hold already requirements and order, so the install process will respect and install in order all requirements for each of your app in the requirements file.

So, if you have your own applications that require others, put your requirements only in your setup files and enroll your main application in the requirements.txt

For third party python apps that don't require compilation you don't have to worry about the order in your requirements.

Otherwise eazy_install becomes deprecated, use pip instead of it.